# Fragment exit animation is not triggered when pressing the back arrow or back button

Tags: android, navigation, android-animation, android-xml, androidx

New to Android development, so forgive me for a silly question.

I see others have asked similar questions but they seem pretty old and I struggle to relate the answers to my code.

I have a one activity with multiple fragments app, and I am using the androidx navigation library.

I notice that my exitAnim is not triggered when I press the back button or back arrow on my fragment.

My navigation xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainMenuFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.MainMenuFragment"
        android:label="Main Menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/main_menu">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_deleteUserFragment"
            app:destination="@id/deleteUserFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/trans_in" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/deleteUserFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.Features.DeleteUser.DeleteUserFragment"
        android:label="Delete User"
        tools:layout="@layout/delete_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_deleteUserFragment_to_clientSelectDialog"
            app:destination="@id/clientSelectDialog" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_deleteUserFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/trans_out"
            app:popUpTo="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/clientSelectDialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/select_client_dialog_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.Features.DeleteUser.ClientSelectDialog"
        android:label="ClientSelectDialog" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_clientSelectDialog_to_deleteUserFragment"
            app:destination="@id/deleteUserFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/deleteUserFragment" />
    </dialog>
</navigation>
```

And this is how I set things in my Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var navController: NavController
...

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.app_green_secondary)))

    ...
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp()
}

}
```

When I press the back button or the back arrow from deleteUserFragment, the exitAnim for the *action_deleteUserFragment_to_mainMenuFragment* action is triggered. How do I get the animation to work?

P.S. I thought perhaps I had to add *app:popExitAnim="@anim/trans_out"* to the action, but that does not work either.

**Update**: I did some debugging by adding a button which performed the navigation action explicitly (deleteUserFragment->mainMenuFragment), and the animation worked. So the question really is, how to make an animation work with back buttons using navigation?

Comment: Are you sure the popExitAnim doesn't work? I usually have to define all 4(boilerplate hell) but it works. (enterAnim,exitAnim,popEnterAnim,popExitAnim). Also why do you specify actions from Delete to Main? Backpress/Up is not enough?

Comment: Nope, popExitAnim doesn't work, nor does specifying everything. How would I set up the animations if I don't specify an action? Coz the animations are set on the action itself.

Comment: I did some debugging by adding a button which performed the navigation action explicitly (deleteUserFragment->mainMenuFragment), and the animation worked. So the question really is, how to make an animation work with back buttons using navigation.

Comment: You specify enter and leave animation. Enter -  means when you navigate to the fragment. Leave - is the animation when you go back in the stack. Just navigateUp from DeleteUser and have animations defined and it should work - (works for me).

Comment: No such luck for me, sadly. I'm thinking of just going manual and making some sort of base fragment with transitions defined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to **explicitly** specify transitions when going back(unless you want to pass some arguments but that doesn't seem to be your case).

From:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:name="xx.xxxx.xxxx.ui.main.MainFragment"
    android:label="XXXX"
    tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_home_to_deliveries"
        app:destination="@id/deliveries"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
```

To:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/deliveries"
    android:name="xx.xxxxx.xxxx.ui.delivery.DeliveryFragment"
    android:label="@string/deliveries"
    tools:layout="@layout/xxxx"/>
```

Animations for going from `deliveries` to `home` are already contained in the `action_home_to_deliveries`.

All you have to do when you want to leave `deliveries` is `navigateUp()`.

P.S. Base fragment for the animations actually might help you remove the boilerplate with animation definitions but it won't solve the core of the issue - you will just redefine this in code(not XML).